# Choosing a value based on a ranking of another column

Tags: powerpivot

I have decent Google-Fu skills, but they've utterly failed me on this.

I'm working in PowerPivot and I'm trying to match up a product with a price point in another table.  Sounds easy, right?  Well each product has several price points, based on the source of the price, with a hierarchy of importance.

For Example:
Product 1 has three prices living in a Pricing Ledger:

Price 1 has an account # of A22011
Price 2 has an account # of B22011
Price 3 has an account # of C22011

Price A overrides Price B which overrides Price C

What I want to do is be able to pull the most relevant price (i.e, that with the highest rank in the hierarchy) when not all price points are being used.

I'd originally used a series of IF statements, but that's when there were only four points.  We now have ten points, and that might grow, so the IF statements are an untenable solution.

I'd appreciate any help.

-Thanks-